# What is the name of this tree with compound leaves?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

Can anyone tell me what is the name of this tree?

It was found in Northern US.

(*click on image to enlarge it*)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it a tree or a shrub? (I can't tell if that's a pot or a trunk.) Whatever, that's one of the prettiest leaves I've ever seen. I hope someone can identify it.

Comment: You have the tree in a pot **1)** so is it a native tree you found and replanted? **2)** Or did you buy it at a nursery or had it given to you? **3)** Did it stay outside through the winter? **4)** If not, has it been subjected to below freezing temperatures - at least briefly? **5)** What part of the northern US as in location (which won't matter if this isn't a native tree or survived the winter)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is ***Cussonia spicata***,  It is one of the favorite foods of wild elephants.

The attractive leafs grow from the end of thick branches to form rounded heads.

[image]

Source

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cussonia_spicata)

Comment: Wonderful that you identified it! I figured it couldn't be any native tree that in NA as its leaves are so unusual, otherwise I'm sure I'd remember seeing it online. I love the leaves but considering it's a tropical tree, not likely to find it in garden shops either. Curious how you knew it - have you been to Africa and saw it there?

Comment: The image you put doesn't have the same type of leaf as in the question. You should argue why you think it corresponds nonetheless. Are the leaves of this plant variable in shape? (I know this is the case in Hedera helix, another Araliaceae).

Comment: This Cussonia leaf looks more like the one on the photo: http://www.zimbabweflora.co.zw/speciesdata/image-display.php?species_id=142930&image_id=6